# Broadcast receiver not running sequentially

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have two functions a and b in my app. Both functions send broadcasts. It is like this:

```
a()  // Method a executed and sends broadcast broadcast_a
b()  // Method b executed and sends broadcast broadcast_b
```

I have toasts in both function a and b as well in the onReceive() of both broadcast receivers. Toasts are displayed in the following order:

```
1. Toast from a()
2. Toast from b()
3. Toast from receiver of broadcast receiver a
4. Toast from receiver of broadcast receiver b
```

I cant understand why this is happening. As far as I know broadcast receiver runs on UI thread, then why is this happening? Shouldn't first toast from receiver of broadcast receiver a be displayed and then from method b? Why does the opposite happen? Can someone please explain this? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Broadcasts are asynchronous. That's not unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the reply !! I get that now